# Binary Tree only adding to the the root

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I'm writing a simple Binary Tree program in C++ and right now it only stores the most recent value entered at the root node eg. if I enter 10 into the tree then 9 into the tree, 9 just overwrites 10 as the root node so the tree only stores the value 9.

I've looked at multiple C++ Binary Tree solutions online and tried their version of implementing them yet I still get no success.

Here is my struct for a single node in the tree

```
struct TreeNode{

    int value;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;

    TreeNode(int value){

        this -> value = value;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;

    }
};
```

My class for the binary tree so far

```
class IntTree{

private :

    TreeNode *root;

public :

    IntTree();
    TreeNode* getRoot();
    void insertValue(TreeNode *root, int intValue);
    TreeNode* searchTree(TreeNode *root, int intValue);
    void inOrder(TreeNode *root);
    void deleteValue(int intValue);
    void deleteTree(TreeNode *root);

};
```

The Insert Method

```
void IntTree::insertValue(TreeNode *root, int intValue){


if(root == NULL){

    root = new TreeNode(intValue);

}

else if(intValue == root->value){

    cout << "Value already exists in the tree" << endl;

}

else if(intValue < root->value){

    insertValue(root->left, intValue);

}

else{

    insertValue(root->right, intValue);

}   
}
```

And then this method is simply called in a menu like this

```
cout << "Enter Value to Insert : " << endl;
input = readInt();
theTree.insertValue(theTree.getRoot(), input);
```

The logic all seems fine to me, apart from that I've tried not using a constructor and just induvidually setting the variable, having two functions for inserting one with just the int parameter which so I don't have to use the getRoot() later on and a million other things which I've forgotten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, the pointer you are modifying is only a copy, so the copy is discarded at the end of the function and you have lost memory. You need to take a reference on the pointer to actually modify it (nothing else to modify):

```
void insertValue(TreeNode *& root, int intValue)
```

Comment: I figured it that it was something to do with me only modifying a copy but I'm new to pointers and wasn't sure what to do. Still a little confused as to what this does, I understand that using the & operator will give the memory address of the root pointer, but I'm not sure what this will do to my program and how I have to change the rest of my program to accommodate for this.

I'm currently getting errors in the line were I call the insertValue function cause the parameters are of different types I think.

Comment: The principle is that if you want to modify an object, you need a pointer (or a reference) on that object. Since this is the pointer to a node you want to modify, you need a pointer on that pointer. Using a reference has the same effect but it allows you to change nothing else but your function signature (in your .h and your .cpp), so it is simpler. The & is not an operator in this case, it means that you take a reference, so you have nothing else to change (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Lvalue_references)). Does it helps?

Comment: Yeah this helps a lot, I understand what you're doing more now. However you say I only need to change the function signature, but I'm still getting errors when I do. These are the errors, I'm getting :  


`no matching function for call to ‘IntTree::insertValue(TreeNode*, int&)’
  theTree.insertValue(theTree.getRoot(), input);`  
`no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘TreeNode*’ to ‘TreeNode*&’`

Comment: This is something i forgot, since you are using a function to get your root, your function should also return a reference on the pointer: `TreeNode*& getRoot();`. Otherwise as it is written in the error message it would take the address of a temporary pointer (the return value) which is not possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer did the trick and you explained it very well, although I also had to add in a return statement, but it's working now.

Comment: No problem, i am glad i was able to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

New insertvalue function call will look as below

```
void insertValue(TreeNode **root, int intValue)
{
  if(*root == NULL)
  {
      *root = newNode(intValue);
  }
  else if(intValue == (*root)->value)
  {
     cout << "Value already exists in the tree" << endl;
  }
  else if(intValue < (*root)->value)
  {
    insertValue(&(*(root))->left, intValue);
  }
  else
  {
    insertValue(&(*(root))->right, intValue);
  }   
}
int main()
{
    //initial code
    insertvalue(&root,value) //root is a single pointer variable.
    //code for printing the tree
}
```

There are many less complex ways to implement the same. i have just modified your code.